# Replace value if the level factor is over 52

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, categorical-data

I'm running a classification algorithm in R with many categorical variables and my problem is that many of them contain more than 52 factors. (53 is the limit for most of classification algo).

Thus, what I want to do is to replace values when the "level" (based on the frequency) is more than 52. 
Meaning: I want to keep the most frequent 52 factor level, and replace the others by "Others".

Here is my code:

```
motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE <- as.factor(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)
var.smry <- motor2%>%
  select(BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)%>%
  group_by(BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(n())

names(var.smry)[2] <- "Count"
var.smry <- var.smry%>%
  arrange(desc(Count))
var.smry$Count <- as.factor(var.smry$Count)

var.smry<- setDT(var.smry, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]

var2 <- var.smry%>%
  select(rn, BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)

motor2 <- (merge(var2, motor2, by = 'BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE'))

motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE <- as.character(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)

motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE <- ifelse(motor2$rn >= 52, ifelse(!is.na(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE),"Other",motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE), motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)

motor2 <- motor2%>%
  select(-rn)

motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE <- as.character(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)
motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE[is.na(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)] <- "missing"
motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE <- as.factor(motor2$BESTUURDER.PERS_POSTCODE)
```

I really don't understand why it is not working...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Allan

Answer (score 0):

This is a toy code doing what you want (without a reproducible example I can't do better):

Creation af a data.frame:

```
db<-data.frame(var=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d"))
levels(db$var)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

nmax_lev=2 #Number of levels without "Others" that you want mantain
Freq<-table(db$var)
Most_freq<- names(head( Freq[order(Freq,decreasing = T)],nmax_lev))
```

Replacing

```
replace<-!(db$var %in% Most_freq)
new_var<-as.character(db$var)
new_var[replace]<-"Other"
```

Your output

```
db[, 'var'] <- as.factor(new_var)
levels(db$var)
[1] "a"     "b"     "Other"
```

Comment: Thanks @Terru_theTerror. However here you're taking the first 2 factor levels that appears when you do head(table(db$var)). What I want to do is to retrieve the most 2 (or 52 in my case) frequent factor level.

Comment: Yes, sorry. There was an error. Code fixed according to this.